# How to Submit Form Data from HTML to Someone's Skype Account

Tags: java, html, forms, skype

[Scenario]
There is a feedback form that allows the user to input his name, email address, subject, and message. Before submitting the form, the user has the option to submit the message via Skype.
If the said option is selected, when the user clicks on the Submit button, the message will be sent to a particular Skype account.

Is this doable? Can a user send a message without having to log in to his own Skype account?

*This particular feature is being requested by the client. I havent started coding yet since Im still trying to see if this request is feasible or not.*

Comment: Why is [tag:java] tagged?

Comment: Because the backend implementation will be using Java

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to send a message to a Skype account without logging into one's own Skype account.

Think of it in a security viewpoint. If anyone could send messages without an account, mostly everything in our Skype inbox will be spam.

But since you have specified [html](/questions/tagged/html), and [forms](/questions/tagged/forms), you can use [Skype URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745883(v=office.15).aspx)'s to open a chat window with a desired topic, but you cannot send instant messages *automatically*.

```
<div id="chat_uri">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
            name: "chat",
            element: "chat_uri",
            participants: ["<target_skype_account>"],
            imageSize: 32,
            imageColor: "white",
            topic: "information you want to send"
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. Thank you very much for your input. Really appreciated it. Will go ahead and read Skype URI first